# TypeScript: how to narrow type of private member by using a function?

Tags: typescript, types, private, member, narrowing

Let's assume I've got the following disposable class:

```
class Data {
  private buffer?: ArrayBuffer;

  constructor(buffer: ArrayBuffer) {
    this.buffer = buffer;
  }

  get data(): ArrayBuffer {
    this.assertNotDisposed();

    return this.buffer;
  }

  dispose(): void {
    this.assertNotDisposed();
    delete (this as Data).buffer;
  }

  private assertNotDisposed(): asserts this is this &
    Required<Pick<Data, 'buffer'>> {
    if (this.buffer === undefined) {
      throw new Error('instance is disposed');
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=3&pln=2&pc=10#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBczQN4ChrQA4CcCWAbogKbQBGArgGZXE4D8AXNAII45gCeAQtbTgG40GaMAD2AOwgIcFYAjE4AFJRp1mbDjz50AlKhGYEACzwQAdKv7QAvOR2CRAX2GYA5sQTQAJojBLdDXYuXjUcA0wjUwtICDoEADkxBFgzLDE47wChQ2gcTwocCWgTM0sHIUwXEW80jOIA5gIxPG8IyNKYqHiklLrM7NzvYhBPUiVO6Eg4P11ysMroasxcQhIp7pxE5NSIdIHAjbitmEmzEujoADJcgCViAEcKPHzvAB4ABTxgAGs3%20CQABpoAByKx0EEAPkh7UweCo0Am0Xm1hsaOgFAkwyoeAkxG8%20nQkQ6xhwYgA7tA8ZSAKLsRRKEG46RgCTAUjnWp7ereEG6RZVZxoFxAA)

As you can see, it uses the method `assertNotDisposed` to ensure the methods can only be called as long as the instance has not been disposed. This method also narrows the type of `this`, so `this.buffer` is not optional anymore, if the instance is not disposed.

Sadly, the above code doesn't work like that, because the member `buffer` is `private` and therefore `Pick<Data, 'buffer'>` fails with `Type '"buffer"' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof Data'`, as `Data` only reflects the `public` interface.

Is there a way to get this to work in a type-safe way while keeping `private buffer`?

Comment: I don't think `private` properties will let you do this at all.  What about refactoring to something like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WYknEN) which uses a generic type parameter to denote the presence or absence of your property?  It's not *exactly* the same, but it behaves in a similar way.

Comment: @jcalz That's an interesting suggestion, but I think I'd rather use `public buffer` and mask it using a dedicated interface, which only exposes `data` and `dispose`. The thing I don't like about the type parameter is that it's irrelevant and confusing for anyone consuming/instantiating the class.